# JQuery parent functions from iframe to document

Tags: jquery, iframe, load, parent

Trying to update content from an iframe on the main document via JQuery load. This does not work, how would one do it.

```
window.parent.$("#OPTthumb").load("http://www.divethegap.com/update/admin/dtg-settings/ #OPTthumb");
```

Any ideas?

Marvellous

THESE DON'T WORK

```
parent.$('#OPTthumb').load("http://www.divethegap.com/update/admin/dtg-settings/ #OPTthumb");

$('#OPTthumb', window.parent.document).load("http://www.divethegap.com/update/admin/dtg-settings/ #OPTthumb");
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use window.parent, use parent.
If you're executing this jQuery in the iframe, use this syntax:

```
parent.$('#OPTthumb').load("http://www.divethegap.com/update/admin/dtg-settings/ #OPTthumb");
```

-edit-
Forgot one thing: for this to work you have to have jquery included in the main page, not necessary in the iframe.